# Need to load images and then insert in mysql

Tags: mysql, file, input

I'm trying to load the names of images (of players) to be uploaded, using a MySQL query. I'm using input type='file'.

```
$sele_players = "SELECT name FROM PLAYERS WHERE nom_team='team'";
$sele_players = mysql_query( $sele_players, $link );

echo "<FORM METHOD='POST'>";
echo "<TABLE>";
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sele_players ) )
{
    echo "<TR><TD>".$row['name']."</TD><TD><INPUT type='file' name='{$row['name']}'> </TD></TR>"; 
}
```

From the MySQL query I receive about 50 entries.  But I don't want to upload photos for *all* the players.  I don't know how to link the name which I get from the database with the image name which is browsed by input type file.  I need a function that knows the name of the image (upload by input file) that can be called before the form is submitted.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `nombre` but it's not in your column list. You need to add it like so:

```
SELECT nombre ...
```

If `nombre` is an alias, then it would look like:

```
SELECT name AS nombre ...
```